# C++ Pass an array as list of arguments to function

Tags: c++

I have an array with some values, but I have no idea how many there are. I would like to pass each value as an argument like this:

```
char const*[] array = {"foo","bar",.../*some other objects*/};
something(array.somethingThatTurnsThisIntoArguments());
```

would this be possible to do? Also, the function `something()` is unchangeable, so I cannot re-write the function with parameters of type `std::vector`

Comment: Nope. Use a std::vector.

Comment: You could require that the array end with `nullptr`, you could pass the size separately, or you could use a standard container that will hold size such as `std::array`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth sorry for my lack of c++ knowledge, but what is a vector?

Comment: @Camden What C++ textbook are you using that does not explain this?

Comment: Use curly brackets `{}` not square `[]` ones for an array initialization.

Comment: If the list is set at compile time, not at runtime (perhaps you just "don't know" ahead of any particular compilation run), then yes it is possible with some ghastly template metahackery (and almost entirely pointless)

Comment: @NeilButterworth I don't use textbooks, I experiment.

Comment: @Camden The chances of you learning C++ properly without using _several_ textbooks are about zero.

Comment: @NeilButterworth its called the internet. I learn through errors. My school doesn't even teach coding. I do it on my own

Comment: " I learn through errors." - the very worst way of learning possible.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ever heard of the phrase "learn from your mistakes"?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer using `std::vector<T>` or `std::array<T,N>` in this situation, where T is the data type and N is an integer specifying the size of the array for `std::array`. Either of these two would work for you just based on what your wrote although the the former can dynamically grow and shrink in size and the latter will have a fixed size. You can assign each a list of objects similar to how you did in your question and then pass them as function arguments without any additional hoops with the right function arguments, like so:

```
void somethingToDo(const std::vector<std::string> &vec) {

    //do something with vec
}

// code

std::vector<std::string> v = {"a","b","c"};
somethingToDo(v);
```

Additionally, I suggest using `std::string` over `char *` or `const char *` for handling strings when you can.

Now, on the second part of your question, you can always get the size of these array-type objects (i.e., the number of objects they contain) by calling each's `size()` member function. Even though you don't know how many objects will be in your array, these objects will keep track of their size for you. You can then query their size at any time in the function you pass the array-type to.

Comment: this function is built into c++

Comment: `size()`? As in `std::vector<T>::size()` or `std::array<T,N>::size()`? Yes, both are "built-in" functions to the C++ standard library.

Comment: No, as in I cannot change the parameter types, because the function something() is unchangable